# Date manipulation in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

Could someone explain to me why the result of

```
SELECT CEIL(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, TO_DATE('30/11/47'))/12) AS AGE FROM DUAL;
```

Give a negative number?? (AGE =-29)

In the other hand, the following result is OK (AGE = 61)

```
SELECT CEIL(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, TO_DATE('30/11/57'))/12) AS AGE FROM DUAL;
```

---

I tried to change the default nls_date_format as suggested!

> Initially I had

[image: Initially:]

> After altering session with nls_date_format, no change!

[image]

Comment: Do not use 2 digit years

Comment: Check your NLS settings, I've executed your first sql and got 1971 as result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I want to avoid 2 digit years but I have to do some queries in an existing table with this date format

Comment: `DATE` columns don't have "a format"

Answer (score 2):

It gives a negative number because it has incorrectly guessed the century.

Be more specific with your date format and the result will be predicable and correct.

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format ='DD-MON-YYYY';

SELECT CEIL(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, TO_DATE('30-NOV-1947'))/12) AS AGE FROM DUAL;


       AGE
----------
        71

1 row selected.
```

The reason the 1957 date works as you expect, I think, is because you have your NLS_DATE_FORMAT set to `DD\MM\RR` which guesses the century differently (iirc it makes it 20 for years less than 50 and 19 from year 50 onwards, instead of YY which always uses 20.  Use YYYY and then Oracle doesn't need to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the format, e.g. `TO_DATE('30/11/47', 'DD-MM-RR')`

However does `47` mean 1947?

`TO_DATE('30/11/47', 'DD-MM-RR')` and `TO_DATE('30/11/47', 'DD-MM-YY')` will result to `2049-11-30` because 47 is lower than 50 (for `RR`), resp. `YY` means current century.

Better use `TO_DATE('30/11/1947', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`